# Is "these both" idiomatic?

Tags: grammar, idiomatic-language

> He had two options, are these both completely viable?

I am not sure why, but it doesn't sound idiomatic although it should be perfectly grammatical? Or is it? And why doesn't it sound idiomatic? Is it idiomatic and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> He had two options, are **these** both completely viable?

The problem here is "these", because you haven't said what "these" refers to. Also "these" has a location reference (something close to you) that hasn't been established.
Instead:

> He had two options, are **they** both completely viable?

where "they" is a general reference.

Comment: It's strange that you can't figure out what "these" refers to but can what "they" refer to. So I don't think the first part of your answer is correct. Though I agree "they" should be in place of "these", but I really don't have any explanation. It might be because of "both", and I think without "both", the original sentence is good to go.

Comment: @Man_From_India Really, more context is needed. In a narrative by itself, "these" seems pointless.